# Another "Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown" error issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I cannot see my layouts in the layout editor. The error message is whats in the title.

Not sure how many of these topics need to exist and why Android is such a black hole when it comes to issues, but I'm still having problem with this:

This project uses:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
```

What I have in my styles file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/menu_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/menu_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/menu_yellow</item>
</style>
```

So the idea was to replace it to Base.Theme.AppComat.Light based on other answers:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    ...
</style>
```

Now this just gives me a "resource not found (Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light)"

Either way I have tried a lot of suggested solutions back from 28 alpha but none of them work now with released 28.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/menu_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/menu_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/menu_yellow</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you
in the styles.xml replace

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```